# My To-Do list project works fine on the localhost but when I deploy it, it behave differently

Tags: javascript, express, server, node-modules, ejs

I was working on a To-Do list project. when it was completed, **it works fine on the localhost but when I deploy it, it behave differently.**

when I go to the website and give them a task it lists the task then when I enter another task, It'll suddenly replace the old task then I enter one more task, this time it lists the task below the previous one.
**This happens at the time of production and not on my local server.**

repo link: https://github.com/GunjanKMishra/ToDoList

deployed link: [https://listyourtodo.cyclic.app](https://listyourtodo.cyclic.app/)

code:

ejs file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To-Do List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <a href="/"><img src="calendar.png"> today</a>
            <a href="/work"><img src="work.png"> work</a>
        </nav>
    </header>

<div class="box">
    <h1>
        <%= day %>, <%= date %>
        <%= month %>
        <%= year %>
    </h1>
</div>
<% if (locals.task) { %>
    <% for( let i=0; i < task.length; i++ ) { %>
        <div class="card">
            <input type="checkbox" name="taskCheckBox" class="checkbox check" id="check<%= i %>">
            <p id="text<%= i %>">
                <%= task[i] %>
            </p>
        </div>
        <% } %>
            <% } %>

                <div class="task">
                    <form action="/" method="post">
                        <input type="text" name="taskItem" class="taskItem" autocomplete="off" required>
                        <input type="submit" value="+" class="btn">
                    </form>
                </div>

                <footer>
                    Copyright © 2023
                </footer>

                <!-- checkbox click strike through feature -->
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script>
                    $("[class^='check']").change(function () {
                        const checkbox = $(this);
                        const text = checkbox.siblings("p")
                        if (checkbox.prop("checked")) {
                            text.css({ "text-decoration": "line-through" });;
                        }
                        else {
                            text.css({ "text-decoration": "none" });;
                        }
                    });
                </script>
                </body>

                </html>
```

index.js file

```
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import expres from "express";

const app = expres();
const port = 3000;

app.use(expres.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

const day = new Date().getDay();
const month = new Date().getMonth();
const date = new Date().getDate();
const year = new Date().getFullYear();

const tasks = {
    today: [],
    work: []
  };

const dayA =['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
const monthA =['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("./index.ejs",{
        day:dayA[day],
        month:monthA[month],
        date: date,
        year: year,
        task: tasks.today,
        });
});

app.get("/work",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("./work.ejs",{task: tasks.work,});
});

app.post("/",(req,res)=>{
    tasks.today.push(req.body['taskItem']);
    res.render("./index.ejs",{
        day:dayA[day],
        month:monthA[month],
        date: date,
        year: year,
        task: tasks.today,
        });
});

app.post("/work",(req,res)=>{
    tasks.work.push(req.body['taskItem']);
    res.render("./work.ejs",{
        task: tasks.work,
        });
});


app.listen(port,()=>{console.log(`server has been sarted at port ${port}!`);});
```

*It actually should list all the task.
but it is not listing tasks perfectly.*

Answer (score -2):

**Analysis:**
The issue with the To-Do list application is that the tasks are not persisting correctly. When a new task is added, it appears on the homepage, but the previous tasks disappear. Additionally, when navigating to the "/work" page, all tasks are listed, but new tasks replace the old ones when added.

The problem arises because the server's state is reinitialized with each new request. This causes the tasks array to reset to empty before rendering the page, leading to the loss of previous tasks.

**Solution:**
To address this problem and ensure tasks persist properly, we need to implement a more persistent data storage approach. Using a database like MongoDB will help store the tasks permanently. By doing so, tasks will be retained even when the server restarts or multiple users interact with the application.

Below is the updated index.js file that integrates MongoDB as the database to store the tasks:

```
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Connect to MongoDB (Make sure to have MongoDB server running)
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/todo_db", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

// Create a schema for the task model
const taskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
});

// Create mongoose model for tasks
const Task = mongoose.model("Task", taskSchema);

const dayA = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
const monthA = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const tasks = await Task.find({});
    res.render("./index.ejs", {
      day: dayA[new Date().getDay()],
      month: monthA[new Date().getMonth()],
      date: new Date().getDate(),
      year: new Date().getFullYear(),
      task: tasks.map(task => task.name),
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching tasks:", error);
    res.status(500).send("Error fetching tasks");
  }
});

app.get("/work", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const tasks = await Task.find({});
    res.render("./work.ejs", {
      task: tasks.map(task => task.name),
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching tasks:", error);
    res.status(500).send("Error fetching tasks");
  }
});

app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const newTask = new Task({
      name: req.body['taskItem'],
    });
    await newTask.save();
    res.redirect("/");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error saving task:", error);
    res.status(500).send("Error saving task");
  }
});

app.post("/work", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const newTask = new Task({
      name: req.body['taskItem'],
    });
    await newTask.save();
    res.redirect("/work");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error saving task:", error);
    res.status(500).send("Error saving task");
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server has been started at port ${port}!`);
});
```

By using MongoDB, your tasks will be saved in the database, and the server will retain the tasks' state correctly. Tasks will now be displayed as a list on the webpage, and new tasks will no longer replace the old ones.

Make sure you have MongoDB installed and running on your local machine before running the code. Additionally, install the required npm packages (`mongoose, express, body-parser`, etc.) using `npm install`.

Feel free to reach out if you have any further questions or need more assistance.

Comment: Why would the server state be initialized on every request? Id it Something specific to the hosting site? It would be peculiar.

Comment: … If I wanted to talk to a bot I’d go directly there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).